# its possible multiple toggle with mdpad or julia markdown?

Tags: jquery, markdown, ijulia-notebook

I'm trying to doing a multiple toggle with markdown pad but don't work:

````
<input type="button" value="Toggle block visibility"    onclick="$('.mdinput div:nth-child(1)').toggle();">




```yaml
     #: name=d
rac: [3.551, 2.232, 1.402, 1.114, 0.882, 0.7]
 gmr: [0.0055611962035177, 0.00700459393067038, 0.00882262274842038,   0.00990159326021141, 0.0111125174323268, 0.0124715326552536]
 conductors: [6, 4, 2, 1, 1/0, 2/0]
```

```yaml
     #: name=rac
 [3.551, 2.232, 1.402, 1.114, 0.882, 0.9]
```


  <input type="button" value="Toggle block visibility2" onmouseenter="$('.mdinput div:nth-child(2)').toggle();">



```yaml
         #: name=d2
  rac: [3.551, 2.232, 1.402, 1.114, 0.882, 0.7]
 gmr: [0.0055611962035177, 0.00700459393067038, 0.00882262274842038,    0.00990159326021141, 0.0111125174323268, 0.0124715326552536]
conductors: [6, 4, 2, 1, 1/0, 2/0]
```
````

Comment: A triple-backtick does not start/end a code block here, use a four space indent. I think the above block is several files, but I cannot understand where each starts and ends, would you repair?

Comment: i have problems with this part this toggle without nth child

Comment: onclick="$('.mdinput div:nth-child(1)').toggle();">

Comment: but toggle the two elements at twice

Comment: I solve my problem editing the html result but if someone have a solution please comment in this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the problem is that i confusing the element this is classes i use something like this

````
           <input type="button" value="Toggle block visibility" onclick="$('.mdinput').eq(1).toggle();">




        ```yaml
              #: name=d
      rac: [3.551, 2.232, 1.402, 1.114, 0.882, 0.7]
         gmr: [0.0055611962035177, 0.00700459393067038,  0.00882262274842038,   0.00990159326021141, 0.0111125174323268,    0.0124715326552536]
              conductors: [6, 4, 2, 1, 1/0, 2/0]
      ```

    ```yaml
 #: name=rac
      [3.551, 2.232, 1.402, 1.114, 0.882, 0.9]
    ```





 <input type="button" value="Toggle block visibility2" onclick="$('.mdinput').eq(2).toggle();">





    ```yaml
                #: name=d2
            rac: [3.551, 2.232, 1.402, 1.114, 0.882, 0.7]
         gmr: [0.0055611962035177, 0.00700459393067038,  0.00882262274842038,    0.00990159326021141, 0.0111125174323268, 0.0124715326552536]
      conductors: [6, 4, 2, 1, 1/0, 2/0]
     ```
````